# Spring Integration: Calling event once certain sets of events have performed their task successfully.

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-integration

I want to perform an event when a certain set of events have performed their task.
E.g

I have following pooling event

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="eventForUpdateProject" channel="updateProjectRequest" entity-manager="entityManagerFactory" 
jpa-query="SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.sysProject.id IS NOT NULL AND p.sysProject.sysupdate != p.updatedAt">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" >
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

It activates three services.

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="updateProjectRequest" ref="S1"></int:service-activator>
<int:service-activator input-channel="updateProjectRequest" ref="S2"></int:service-activator>
<int:service-activator input-channel="updateProjectRequest" ref="S3"></int:service-activator>
```

Now i want to trigger a forth event once all these events have performed their tasks. Any idea How this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tricks for such a task.

1. `<aggregator>`, when all those your services send their result for some correlation. The group release on the `<aggregator>` is performed only when `release-strategy` has met the requirements.
2. `<publish-subscribe-channel>` without any `executor` and with all your services as subscribers. Plus that your 4th one. Looks like it is your case, although you don't show the `updateProjectRequest` configuration. Without an executor all the subscribers get the same message one by one: the second subscriber performs his task only when the first has finished. Therefore your "forth event" will be triggered only after all previous.
3. `<recipient-list-router>` with similar semantics like previous approach but on several sequential channels.

I'd say that the first one is the best because you can use the same `<publish-subscribe-channel>` but already with an `executor` and all your services will be performed in parallel. Even if you don't have anything to return from those services you can emulate aggregation and correlation with a pair of service activators on the same sync `<recipient-list-router>` where the first one is one of your real service and the second is just for sending some artificial message for aggregation. All those `<recipient-list-router>`s should be subscribed on the async `<publish-subscribe-channel>`.

Comment: The Info which you have provided have helped me a lot, but there are still some confusion, I'm not able to understand concept of "correlation" in "aggregator". Can you please explain it a bit.

Comment: See more info about that in the Reference Manual http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

Comment: Thanks. It helped.